# Modified shortest path using Dijkstra's or Bellman–Ford's algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm, shortest-path, dijkstra, bellman-ford

How can we use Dijkstra's or Bellman–Ford's algorithm to find shortest path in a graph whose some of edges are affected if we go specific vertices. Such that, the affected edge's length will be more than or less than the original length.

Comment: With the information you are providing there is little that can be stated. Can edge's become negative at any point? Do edge's cost get modified only when either end is visited, or also by means of third nodes being visited? Is there any other guarantee?

Comment: Can you provide an example of such affected graph? Say, edge AB has length 3, but if you also visit node C, AB's length will be 5. Is this what you mean?

Comment: @Nikita Rybak Exactly how you told; "Edge AB has length 3, but if you also visit node C, AB's length will be 5."

Comment: @ David Rodriguez  No negative point. Not just with the end is visited, as Nikita told, any node can change any node's cost.

Comment: @Alock How different 'visitations' affect single edge? Say, you visited C and D, C says |AB|=5 and D says |AB|=7.

Comment: @Nikita Rybak Meanwhile i forgot to tell you that C and D can not be both in path; i'm sorry. The nodes that affects same node can not be in the same path. Therefore just C's or D's effect is valid. But there exist a lot of tuples not just C and D.

Comment: Is there any other constraint that has not been stated? In particular on paths that contain a node that changes values from other edges, with respect to those edges. I guess that a higher level description of the problem to solve can help in providing possible solutions. Also, consider redefining the same problem where the edges are fixed by maybe splitting the edges into the two separate values, and at the end validating each one of the paths... but I am not sure that this will get you close to the solution. Looks like a hard enough problem (NP-complete?)

Comment: How many nodes are there in total? How many nodes edges can change their cost?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand this right, you want to change the cost of an edge in a graph depending on nodes which are visited in your current path. An example from the comments is:

"Edge AB has length 3, but if you also visit node C, AB's length will be 5"

Now, there doesn't seem to be a way for something like Djikstra's algorithm to be used as there is a greedy step in that algorithm which picks the 'best' node at every stage. The notion that the 'best' node at that point may change at a later time (due to a rule such as above) violates the concept of the greedy approach which assumes that we are effectively visiting nodes in order from best to worst cost. I'm not certain if this is NP hard as suggested but it certainly cannot use a Dijikstra kind of approach from the start. +1 for the problem though.